# How do I remove the javascript blocking from some links?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

For example, I am trying to change this:

```
<a href="javascript: void(null)" class="jv-redirectCandidate" 
    key="pcxe7gwP"
>Some Name</a>
```

Into this:

```
<a href="https://www.foo.com/something.aspx?p=pcxe7gwP">Some Name</a>
```

I need the string "pcxe7gwP" that is currently part of

```
key="pcxe7gwp"
```

and then I want to attach it to part of a URL

```
https://www.foo.com/something.aspx?p=
```

and the use that as the `href` in place of the current

```
"javascript: void(null)"
```

I am using the Tampermonkey Chrome extension and trying to create a userscript to accomplish this. I am new to userscripts and would love any help.  Thanks!

Comment: Hint, hint: the `<a>` has a class `jv-redirectCandidate`. Act on all members with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test in Greasemonkey, don't need jquery.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Change link href with it's key
// @namespace   test
// @grant       none
// @version     1
// @include     http://localhost:8000/*.html
// ==/UserScript==

var prefix = 'https://www.foo.com/something.aspx?p=';
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a.jv-redirectCandidate[key]');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i += 1) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.href = prefix + link.getAttribute('key');
}
```

Comment: You might not *need* jQuery, just like you don't *need* a good cordless drill.  But both make jobs a lot easier.  jQuery is an excellent habit to encourage beginners to get into.

Comment: I mean is my version don't need jquery, let asker to reference, is not tell others don't use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, this is what you are looking for:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeHREF(element){
    element.href = "https://www.foo.com/something.aspx?p=" + element.key;
}
</script>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:changeHREF(this);" class="jv-redirectCandidate" key="pcxe7gwP" id="myId">Some Name</a>
</body></html>
```

Another possible solution:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeHREF(){
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName("jv-redirectCandidate");
    for(i = 0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].href = "https://www.foo.com/something.aspx?p=" + elements[i].getAttribute("key");
    }
}
</script>
<body onload="javascript:changeHREF()">
<a href="javascript:void(null);" class="jv-redirectCandidate" key="pcxe7gwP">Some Name</a>
</body></html>
```

Well, there are other solutions to achieve the same results. But, I think that it is out of topic.

Cheers

Comment: The first part won't work, as the OP does not control the page. It's a content/user-script question.  The JS *code* from the second part looks workable, but is packaged incorrectly for a script.  If you want, I can adjust your answer (and then upvote it).

Comment: @BrockAdams, I see what you mean. I did not realise the question requires a solution for Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey and therefore I have written a regular HTML/Javascript code. Thank you for offering help. No need to fix my answer because I think your answer is already correct :)

Comment: Thanks! I went with muzuiget's solution as it was the first one I tried and it worked. I'm sure your's does too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **a complete script** that will work in either Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey.  It use's [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for ease and power:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _De-javascript links
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
//-- Get links with the class "jv-redirectCandidate".
var linksToFix = $("a.jv-redirectCandidate");

//-- Loop through the links
linksToFix.each ( function () {
    var jThis   = $(this);  //-- An individual link
    var key     = jThis.attr ("key");

    jThis.attr ("href", "https://www.foo.com/something.aspx?p=" + key);
} );
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with muzuiget's solution as it was the first one I tried but I really appreciate your solution.

Comment: You're welcome.  But choosing an answer because it was the first one you tried that worked is not wise, See [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/148310), especially this guidance: `"Make sure that besides working for you, the answer is really good practice. Sometimes after the answer gets accepted, another comes in, uncovering the fact that previous one was in fact a bad hack."`.